# How to stop Eclipse from hanging on a long autocompletion list?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using the GL class from JOGL, which basically contains *all* OpenGL functions. Now I just installed the Javadoc for JOGL, because it's nice to have the parameter names if you can't remember the order.

However, with this Javadoc installed, it takes about *half a minute* to show the autocompletion list whenever I type `GL.`. Since I'm making a lot of OpenGL calls, this is hugely annoying.

Apart from uninstalling or disabling the JOGL Javadoc, is there any way to make the list appear faster, or not at all?

Comment: which eclipse are you using ? 3.4 ? and which java do you use to execute it ? (6_u7 ?) and how do you access the GL library ? (through network or directly on your local hard disk ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist

Try some different settings in the "Auto-Activation" frame.

Comment: For now, I turned it off completely, but that is hardly a decent solution. Maybe I should submit a bug report...

Comment: Yes in the debug console there is an exception:

!MESSAGE Exception while processing quick fixes or quick assists

!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.OperationCanceledException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.CompletionEngine.checkCancel(CompletionEngine.java:1940)

Using eclipse:
Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552